# Prevent Code Execution from External Acess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Here is my directory structure

```
root
    private
    public
```

Using .htaccess and/or httpd.conf, I want to limit access to the private folder to only code executed from the root folder.  So, no external access to anything in the private folder.  Honestly, I have tried a lot of options, but nothing seems to work.

My test environment is XAMPP - installed on my local machine.

**EDIT**

One of the issues I encountered was using the wrong directory path.  I created a simple PHP page with just phpinfo()

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

In the **PHP Variables** section, I looked for **_SERVER["CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT"]**.  I used this for the directory path and then added **private** (the folder in the root that I wanted to limit access to).  Thus, my completed code in the httpd.conf is below:

```
<Directory "E:/xampp/htdocs/home/private">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Order deny,allow`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order) and [`Deny from all`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html#deny) should be already sufficient

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

If you put this in a .htaccess in the `private` folder, all access from outside will be prohibited.

Alternatively, you can put it in a [`<Directory /path/to/root/private>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) in httpd.conf, which has the same effect

```
<Directory /path/to/root/private>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

**Update**:

According to [Apache HTTP Server Tutorial: .htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) you should prefer httpd.conf over .htaccess files

> You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.

Comment: Is there any practical difference between putting it in .htaccess or in httpd.conf?